# Hide adjacent duplicates comparing visible fields in SALV

Tags: abap, alv

Consider the heading (ABAP) pseudo code on a SALV-Grid.
I need something like this, or, some way to remove the visual vertical bloating of rows in the grid when the columns that differentiate them are hidden.
After a lot of reasearch, I doubt that such a thing exists, so I need to work around it.

I want to change just the view, I don't want to modify the underlying internal table.
Any ideas on how to best accomplish this? Events maybe?

Comment: I seriously doubt you can influence the "visuality" of the SALV-Grid in SAP GUI. Secondly, can you please explain what "bloating of rows" mean?

Comment: Have a look at the second table here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989409/suppress-duplicate-entriescolumn-in-report-write-and-alv
With my settings of SALV, multiple visually equal rows appear like one combined big ("tall") row, i.e. horizonatally separating lines are omitted.

Comment: So do you want to have this separating vertical lines while the cells still remain empty but the first one?

Comment: No, I want to get rid of the rows that show no addtional information (visually empty rows)

Comment: ?SYNTAX ERROR <blinking blue cursor>

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the data from your table and remove duplicates from the copy.  Pass the copy to your grid.  The hurdle here would be ensuring you update the original table if edit, delete, and create functionality is enabled in your grid.